# How to implement custom Specificty metric in Tensorflow2.x?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, precision-recall, semantic-segmentation

I am trying to implement a custom metric that calculates Specificity for my semantic segmentation problem. I keep getting this error when I train the model using this metric. This metric works well when the model is showing the training metrics but stops for the validation metrics as shown below.

My implementation is shown below:

```
class Specificity(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.tn = tf.keras.metrics.TrueNegatives()
    self.fp = tf.keras.metrics.FalsePositives()

def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
    self.tn.update_state(y_true, y_pred)
    self.fp.update_state(y_true, y_pred)
    
def result(self):
    tn = self.tn.result()
    fp = self.fp.result()
    return tf.expand_dims(tf.divide(tn, tn + fp), axis=-1)
```

Output Message:

```
Epoch 1/200
2022-07-26 10:16:25.238678: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:384] Loaded cuDNN version 8302
2022-07-26 10:16:26.083645: I tensorflow/core/platform/default/subprocess.cc:304] Start cannot spawn child process: No such file or directory
100/100 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.7601 - iou_score: 0.5211 - precision: 0.6069 - recall: 0.7806 - f1-score: 0.6732 - auc: 0.9403 - specificity: 0.8967Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bhattrai/corneal_neovascularization_tf2/test_statistics.py", line 892, in <module>
    history = model.fit(my_generator, validation_data=validation_datagen, steps_per_epoch=100, validation_steps=100,
  File "/home/bhattrai/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/home/bhattrai/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/backend.py", line 4028, in batch_set_value
    x.assign(np.asarray(value, dtype=dtype_numpy(x)))
ValueError: Cannot assign value to variable ' accumulator:0': Shape mismatch.The variable shape (1,), and the assigned value shape () are incompatible.
2022-07-26 10:16:39.142482: W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:108] Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: FAILED_PRECONDITION: Python interpreter state is not initialized. The process may be terminated.
         [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
```

I tried implementing it in another way as shown below but when I use it during model training it always shows 0.000.

```
import tensorflow as tf

class Specificity(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):
    def __init__(self, name='specificity', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.tn = self.add_weight(name='tn', initializer='zeros')
        self.fp = self.add_weight(name='fp', initializer='zeros')
        self.tnr = self.add_weight(name='tnr', initializer='zeros')

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        y_true = tf.cast(y_true, tf.bool)
        y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred, tf.bool)

        # Getting the True Negatives
        values = tf.logical_and(tf.equal(y_true, False), tf.equal(y_pred, False))
        values = tf.cast(values, self.dtype)
        self.tn.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(values))

        # Getting the False Positives
        values = tf.logical_and(tf.equal(y_true, False), tf.equal(y_pred, True))
        values = tf.cast(values, self.dtype)
        self.fp.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(values))

        self.tnr.assign_add(tf.divide(self.tn, tf.add(self.tn, self.fp)))

    def result(self):
        return self.tnr
```

Output:

```
m = Specificity()
m.update_state([0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0])
X = m.result().numpy()
1.0
```

But when I use it to train a model:

```
X = tf.random.normal(shape=(100, 256, 256, 3))
Y = tf.random.uniform(minval=0, maxval=2, shape=(100, 256, 256, 1), dtype=tf.int32)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X,Y))
train = dataset.take(80)
val = dataset.skip(80)
train = train.cache().shuffle(1000).batch(32).prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
val = val.cache().shuffle(1000).batch(32).prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
                         tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(256,256,3)),
                         tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same'),
                         tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
                         tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same'),
                         tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
                         tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same'),
                         tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
                         tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, strides=2, padding='same', kernel_size=3),
                         tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, strides=2, padding='same', kernel_size=3),
                         tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, strides=2, padding='same', kernel_size=3),
                         tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, 3, activation='sigmoid', padding="same")
])

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
          optimizer='adam',
          metrics=[Specificity(), 'accuracy'])

model.fit(train, validation_data=val, epochs=2)

Epoch 1/2
3/3 [==============================] - 16s 5s/step - loss: 0.6939 - specificity: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5003 - val_loss: 0.6934 - val_specificity: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.4999
Epoch 2/2
3/3 [==============================] - 15s 5s/step - loss: 0.6933 - specificity: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5004 - val_loss: 0.6933 - val_specificity: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.5002
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f9fdb2c1250>
```

Comment: I tried with and without the tf.expand_dim(), but the problem remains.

Comment: What is the shape of your train vs validation set?

Comment: Training:  (340, 128, 128, 3)
Validation:  (60, 128, 128, 3).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to test it right now, however I've always defined custom metrics as functions (not by subclassing). Maybe you could give it a try. Also in this [article](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/custom-metrics-for-keras-tensorflow-ae7036654e05) I've found an implementation of the Specificity measure, maybe you can adapt it for your needs.

This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K

def specificity(y_true, y_pred):
    tn = K.sum(K.round(K.clip((1 - y_true) * (1 - y_pred), 0, 1)))
    fp = K.sum(K.round(K.clip((1 - y_true) * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    return tn / (tn + fp + K.epsilon())

model = tf.keras.Sequential(...)
model.compile(
    optimizer="adam",
    loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
    metrics=[
        "accuracy",
        specificity
    ]
)
model.fit(train, validation_data=val, epochs=2)
```

**Update:**

In your subclass version maybe the problem is related to missing the `reset_states` function (clears the state after each epoch). Try adding this to your class:

```
def reset_states(self):
    self.self.tn.assign(0)
    self.self.tp.assign(0)
    self.self.tnr.assign(0)
```

Comment: I also implemented it similarly and it works. But I Want to understand the subclassing approach.

Comment: Sure, no problem, I've updated the answer @Na462

Comment: It didn't work. The above code is just insurance to reset the states after every epoch. But it doesn't solve the problem. I find it hard to understand as for some distinct examples it works(as shown above) but while using it to train the model it doesnt. I also tried to print the intermediate result. like self.tn etc... All are zeros always. I dont know why? :(

Comment: Mmm, yes that's a bit weird. I suggest you to use lots of tf.print(...) inside your `update_state` to figure out which operation causes the problem. Debugging this stuff is not easy @Na462